# Extract data from JSX elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this example:

```
const items = data.get('$$items');

const row = items.map((item) =>
  <tr key={item.get('id')} onClick={this.handleClick}>
    <td>{item.get('id')}</td>
    <td>{item.get('value1')}</td>
    <td>
      {  
        this.props.editing ? 
        <input value={item.get('value2')}> :
        <span>item.get('value2')</span>
      }
    </td>
    <td>{item.get('value3')}</td>
    <td>{item.get('value5')}</td>
    <td>{item.get('value5')}</td>
  </tr>
);

return (
  <section>
    <table>
      <thead>
       ...
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        { row }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
```

Does React provide a way to conveniently (without interacting with the DOM) gather values of each `td` in a single object? Or even to iterate through each `tr`, processing data into objects. What I mean is like having a Backbone model, without actually having one.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Your data is already in `items`, why do you need to loop it through virtual DOM and back? Traverse initial data instead. It's more efficient and will make other programmers who would take over your code thank you for not inventing a bicycle.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin The data in table may change via user input, I would like to it persist it on the server.

Comment: if the user changes the data, it should go back into the item or at least the component state.

Comment: @dandavis, an `item` in the table represents a corresponding model on the server, the component has `dispatch` method injected with all necessary actions, but before dispatching an action that will submit the data, I have to assemble an object with all its properties. I.e. I could loop over `tr > td` and create desired object using jQuery and then pass this object to dispatch, but I don't want to traverse the DOM.

Comment: So are there input fields in the `<td>`s you omitted?  If so, you removed the most crucial part of the code.  If not, then whatever is updated the `<td>` elements should instead be updating the items, which in turn will update the view.

Comment: I think we're close enough to giving a super basic, yet right, answer about component state and how rendering a component works. OP, please consider using component state and change the state through listening to `onChange` events fired by input fields.

Comment: @gravityplanx, you are right, I've update the code, my apologies.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin, this is a stateless components with all its data inject via props from parent, which is connected to the Redux store and gets entire `items` collection from the global state. Now that I have injected data into the table, along with `onChange` or `onBlur` handler which, at least how I see it, should dispatch an action that will eventually submit data to the server. But in order to submit the data I need an object that will look like {'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'value' ... }, whilst event handler will have access only to the `td` that was edited. And I need an entire `tr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you could handle this.

1. onChange event handlers.

On your input field, include;

```
<input value={item.get('value2')} onChange={this.handleChange}>
```

And then elsewhere in your component, add a handleChange function:

```
handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({value2: event.target.value});
}
```

Using your component's state to maintaint the current values of "item".

2. use Refs, and pull that data dynamically when requested.

If you don't want to store the information in your state, you can instead expand your input as such:

```
<input value={item.get('value2')} ref="value2_input">
```

After doing so, you'll be able to access this input field from any function on the component through;

```
this.refs.value2_input.value
```

Comment: Seems like the `refs` is what I'm looking for. Can I do something like `<tr ref='item_${item.get('id')}'>` and then gather values of each nested `td` of this `tr`? Or I have to designate each input with its own `ref` key and then create object like `{'value1': '{this.refs.value1_input.value}', {'value2': '{this.refs.value2_input.value}' ... }` Because even if only one attribute changes, server still expects all of the properties in the payload.

Comment: You'll want to do it on an input level.  You certainly can ref an entire row, but it has no way of knowing how to convert that into an object of any specified format.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've been a great help!